# Click on the checkbox inside div which changes the state of the checkbox. jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Can someone help me with this problem?

```js
$('.check_group').click(function () {
    var check = $(this).children('input')[0];
    check.checked = !check.checked;
    alert(check.checked);
    //run something else
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check_group" style="background-color: rgb(200, 138, 59);">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

So, when I click on the checkbox - change the state of the checkbox, and then triggered jQuery and status changes back.

How to make so that when you click on the div / Checkbox - checkbox has changed and there is an alert?

Comment: Nice challenge!!! Noticed that in Firefox (checked on 47) it is working as you expected but not on Google chrome, and I am not brave enough to check on IE... lol

Comment: What exactly does not work? Temporary solution (my answer) working in IE and Google chrome..

Comment: @Pavel : Did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, you need to identify when the DIV is clicked then you need to make that check-box checked/unchecked.

```js
$('.check_group').click(function (e) {
    var input = $(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]');
    //Identify the node which is clicked
    if(e.target.nodeName == "DIV")
    {
      $(input).prop('checked', !$(input).prop("checked"));
    }
    console.log($(input).is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check_group" style="background-color: rgb(200, 138, 59);">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this ?

```js
$('.check_group').click(function () {
    var checkbox = $(this).children('input')[0];
    setTimeout(function(){alert(checkbox.checked);},200);
    //run something else
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check_group" style="background-color: rgb(200, 138, 59);">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

setTimeout is not required unless you want visually show check first and then alert

Comment: I need change checkbox-status when i clicking in the Div. "check.checked = !check.checked;" - it's impotant. Your code have this same problem, but worke slower =)

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:

```js
$('.check_group').click(function (e) {
    var check = $(this).children('input')[0];
    if (e.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
         check.checked = !check.checked;
    }
    check.checked = !check.checked;
    alert(check.checked);
    //
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check_group" style="background-color: rgb(200, 138, 59);">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```